# Passing Multidimenionall Arrays through C++ functiones

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int ROWS = 3;
int COLS = 4;
```

How do I solve this c++ multidimensionalArray problem? I have been working on this for some time but I just cant figiure it out, thank you verry much

```
void fillScores(int [ROWS][COLS]);

int main() {
    int scores[ROWS][COLS] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
    fillScores(scores);
    return 0;
}

void fillScores(int newScores[ROWS][COLS]) {
    cout << newScores[1][1]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: you need to define `ROWS` with `static const int` - they are compilation constants.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the array in a struct and then pass it by address, where you need.

```
struct ArrayWrapper
{
   int _arr[ROWS][COLS];
};
```